# Is it possible upgrade ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 without losing development configurations?

Tags: upgrade

Currently Canonical is no longer supporting ubuntu 13.04, so I wonder if (and I'm asking only for my currently work's project that are a PITA to reinstall, don't ask why) upgrading will lose my config.

Previous version I know that I every installation, but I want to know if for there is anyway that I could upgrade without this reinstallation of my development tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade through the upgrade tool, should keep your applications and configurations and only upgrade the system files.